# magento 1.9 add product to cart not working from an external URL

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to add a product to cart from an external php script. following is the code, but it's not adding the product to the cart.

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();

$id = '2'; // product id
$qty = '1'; // qty

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below code

```html
<?php
include '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
// Need for start the session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
try {
    $product_id = '1'; // Replace id with your product id
    $qty = '1'; // Replace qty with your qty
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');
     header('Location: ' . '../index.php/checkout/cart/');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

All so make sure that you have product with id 1 exists and also enough quantity.

I had try above code it work perfectly for me.

My folder structure is magento/test/test.php

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: It worked, but in my case the problem is that I have multiple sites on Magento. I have a site called Brand1 another Brand2. Magento does not allow me to have 1 shopping cart between multiple sites, so  I am trying to inject the products from Brand1 to Brand2. 

This means that I have to do more validations and stuff :(

Comment: Hi Sagar, How to pass custom options(required) with this code.